# Poitou-Tate dualities for Galois representations into power series rings?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, $A=K[[T_1,\dots,T_n]]$, $V$ a finite-rank free $A$-module, and $\rho:G_{\mathbf{Q}} \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ a continuous Galois representation.  Are there analogues of Poitou-Tate dualtiy and the Tate local and global Euler characteristic formulas for the cohomology groups $H^i_{\mathrm{cont}}(G_{\mathbf{Q}},V)$, $H^i_{\mathrm{cont}}(G_{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}},V)$?  I was hoping I could "take the limit" of the formulas for the groups $H^i(G,V/(T_1^j,\dots,T_n^j)V)$ as $j\to\infty$, but that doesn't seem so easy...

Comment: If this is true the argument of Kisin, Overconvergent modular forms and the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture, Lemma 9.7 should give it to you.

Comment: You could take a look Nekovář's *Selmer complexes*. Also, you probably want $\mathcal{O}_K[[T_1,\dots,T_n]]$ (or that tenor $K$).

Comment: which, btw, is available on his website: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~nekovar/pu/sel.ps

Comment: @Rob H.: Thanks for the reference! And yes, I did want the tensor product you suggest.

Comment: Have you asked Jay Pottharst or Joel Bellaiche, both of whom are in your neighbourhood, and both of whom will have thought about this kind of question?  Regards, Matthew

Comment: By the way, the long story short is that yes indeed Poitou-Tate and Artin-Verdier dualities will carry through pretty much in the way you imagine. Euler characteristics will also carry through seamlessly but will involve Hilbert-Samuel multiplicities. 

Comment: @Matthew: Good idea, thanks a lot for the pointer! @Olivier: Great!

Answer (score 2):

See the recent work of Meng Fa Lim (with Sharifi)
(1) [Poitou-Tate duality over extensions of global fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1484)

(2) [Nekovar duality over p-adic Lie extensions of global fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1230)